# Function to access to a tensor in Theano

Tags: theano

I'm working with Theano library.
I have 1000 object of size 114, defined as a variable of size 1000x114.
I have a function that takes that variable and produces 1000 numbers between 0 and 113.
I need to create a function that takes for each one of the 1000 object, the number in the position given by the previous function.
How can I do it?

This is what works:

```
input_var = T.imatrix('inputs')
index = something
index_fn = theano.function([input_var], index, name="index function")
```

This is what doesn't work:

```
num = input_var[:][index + 48]
num_fn = theano.function([input_var], num, name="num function")
```

The result of the num_fn is simply the same data I give it as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm don't know what the +48 is supposed to do but I'm assuming index + 48 is your vector of indices your function returned. The way theano (and numpy) indexing works is that your second approach, using :, will return the rows with indices in index. Instead, you need to use a range, e.g.:

```
num = input_var[T.arange(T.shape(input_var)[0]), index + 48]
num_fn = theano.function([input_var], num, name="num function")
```